# Instagram post that won't delete

Tags: instagram, photos

Having an issue on #Instagram. A post is showing up in our account that we can't delete. https://www.instagram.com/p/BFe0ykVNdF1

Has anyone had this experience before? It is showing up in our "heart" section, but not as a post that we can delete.

JB

Answer (score 0):

You **can not delete posts** from your computer. You **can only delete it using its official android / windows/ ios app.**To delete a photo or video that you've posted, tap (iPhone and Windows Phone) or (Android) above your post you will have 3 dots which on clicking will display a delete option and then tap Delete. It isn't possible right now to delete multiple posts at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The "delete" option is not available on this particular post for some reason. There is a bug in it. This post isn't even in our photo post feed. We don't know where it is or how it got there or where to find it to delete it.